# Square donuts in Dubai

Tags: food-and-drink, local-customs, dubai, local-cuisine

I've been in Dubai some time ago and in a Starbucks I've found square donuts.

Can you explain why? Is there a religious rule?

Comment: Religious rule regarding square donuts? sure, our God Of Donuts ordered us to make them all square!

Comment: They might not like hot cross buns, preferring crescent buns. "Talibuns" http://cnsnews.com/news/article/talibuns-hot-cross-buns-islamic-halal-symbol-spark-debate

Comment: Sorcery!! I have never even seen Square Donuts.

Comment: yes, to us Muslims, round donuts are considered as the food of Satan, because Adam was deceived by the Satan with a round shiny donuts, and that eternal roundness of the donuts made the Satan so fallen. Therefore, all donuts in all Muslim countries are made in square deliberately. Even you might get prosecuted if you walk on the street of Dubai with a round donuts in your hand. Round donuts are very offensive.

Comment: LOL. @ramgorur ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that is just for aesthetical reasons.

There are stores in Dubai that do sell round doughnuts, such as [Dunkin Donuts](http://www.dunkindonutsuae.com/bakery.html), [Krispy Kreme](http://www.zomato.com/dubai/krispy-kreme-mall-of-the-emirates/menu) or [other stores](http://www.timeoutdubai.com/restaurants/features/11409-go-nuts-for-doughnuts#.U3MBZRCkuSw), the only reference to square doughnuts in Dubai that I could find was the ones at [Starbucks](http://therealgoodnews.tumblr.com/image/61792033708).

Also on the other hand there are square doughnuts for instance in [the US](http://www.squaredonuts.com/index.html), without any mention to it be for any religious or cultural reason. According to this [Time article](http://newsfeed.time.com/2013/06/07/great-doughnut-innovations-since-1958/), they started producing it for purely practical reasons:

> Square Donuts in Indianapolis started making boxy doughnuts kind of by accident, when the manufacturer of its doughnut cutters gave a square cutter to Rich Comer, the store’s founder.

Comment: Square donuts? Old and busted. New hotness: triangle donuts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Bobby (c. 1920s, as it happens)

Comment: I guess old becomes new again. :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamantash

Comment: Wow! Gotta try the square donut!! :D

Comment: "Thou shall eat only of the one, the Holy, the circle of goodness. Thou shall not partake of the three, for that is consuming the Trinity, and that shall not be allowed. Nay the Four, for it is truly the work of the Devil." :)